# div tag not showing up on asp button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have the following code in script tag:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#Button1').click(function () {
         $("#loading").show(500000);
     });
 });
```

and here is the button and the div tag:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="View Summary" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </p>
    <div id="loading">Page is loading...</div>
```

when I click the button, div tag is not showing up. I have  **display:none;**
for div in css..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You button is rendered by asp.net and it changes the id (unless you have set the static id mode) so when rendered id of the button will not be `Button1` instead it will have other things appended to it (to avoid id duplication as much as possible). So use the [ClientId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to register the click handler. Also the duration for `show` animation is in milliseconds and you have it too long, just shorten it up a bit as well.

Try:-

```
  $('#<%= Button1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
     $("#loading").show();
  });
```

Another approach it to provide a CssClass to your button and bind the handler to that as the selector.

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="Button1" Text="View Summary" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

and

```
 $('.Button1').click(function () {
     $("#loading").show();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#loading").show(500000);
```

Is going to take like 500 seconds to show up.

Try

```
$("#loading").show();
```

The argument in show indicates how many milliseconds it takes before the element shows up.  Leaving no argument in `show()` defaults to `.show(400)`

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I tried with $("#loading").show(); still it is not showing up.